# Change Approval Request Email Template / from Address

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I know that when a record in an approval process is in **pending**, the organization receives an email that has the link to approve/reject the record. I tried finding where in salesforce can I edit the email template/from address.

1. Is it possible to **change** the **from email address** of the **approval request template** to **Organization-Wide Email** used in the **approval process**?
2. Is it possible to **edit/override** the **contents** of the **Approval Request Email** from Salesforce?

Comment: For #1, why would you want to do this?  You would then lose traceability and transparency back to the user who requested the approval process

Comment: I was just wondering about its possibilities. I was asked to try it so I begun searching for it but I can't find the settings for it in my org.